# Google Compute Engine aiohttp get requests recaptcha

Tags: google-cloud-platform, python-requests, google-compute-engine, recaptcha, aiohttp

I am trying to send a get request on Google Compute Engine (GCE) to Newegg using aiohttp. Upon doing so, I get back the webpage "Are you a human." However, when I run the same exact code on my local machine, I am able to retrieve the page just fine. Does anyone know why:

1. I only get the Recaptcha page with GCE, but not my local machine?
2. Is there any way to avoid or get around this Recaptcha page on GCE?

my code:

```
import asyncio from bs4 import BeautifulSoup import aiohttp

async def myDriver():
    await httpReq()

async def httpReq():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get("https://www.newegg.com/") as page:
            responseCode = page.status
            print(responseCode)
            
            pageContent = await page.text()
            content = BeautifulSoup(pageContent, 'lxml')
            print(content.prettify())

asyncio.run(myDriver())
```

page reached:

```
200
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <title>
   Are you a human?
  </title>
.
.
.
grecaptcha.ready(function()
```

Notes:

- "Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
- python 3.7.3
- aiohttp 3.6.3
- I've tried similar code with the normal requests library on GCE, and everything works fine, so this is only an issue with aiohttp on GCE.
- I must use aiohttp and not the normal requests library for my project

Comment: The reCaptcha is working. It is detecting that your code is not a human. Why it does not detect this on your workstation could be that you have already been to the site in a browser and they remember you. The low level details are not public. If they were public, hackers would know how to get around them. The final point is that your code is not a human. That site only wants humans and not bots. There is no workaround except for temporary hacks.

Comment: Alrighty, thanks for the advice!